# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when try to access port 80

Tags: linux, azure, httpd, azure-networking

I have Azure Linux VM created with httpd running on port 80, here is putty:

[image]

I have enabled/allowed azure vm security group to allow port 80 traffic.

[image]

When I try to access this vm from my browser using URL, http://boxpublicip:80, getting `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`any idea what am I missing?

NOTE: My SSH is working fine. This is only issue with port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

To see the firewall configuration on the VM side, just to see if port 80 is open on the VM firewall?

Comment: This is correct. It seems RHEL VM has firewall blocking the incoming traffic on this port. Once I opened the firewall was able to access the port.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the network connection is working properly on your end. Also you can use `telnet ip address 80` to make sure the port 80 is listening. After that, there are possible web application issues causing this error.

For the error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`, you can check the methods 1-5 referring to this [link.](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/err-connection-timed-out/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried telnet, the message was: Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed. I am pretty sure that ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT is due to this couldn't open connection to 80, not due to the issues you linked.

Comment: Please verify if there is a rule to allow port 80 with the firewall on the Azure VM. And do you have a proxy set locally. Can you access another websites by using URL http:xxx normally?